# Higlight an effect in an equation using `underset` in combination with `xleftarrow`

Tags: beamer, equations

I would like to highlight a certain effect in an equation using either `underbrace` or `underset` in combination with `xleftarrow`. However, I am not very satisfied with the result of `underbrace` as you can see in my MWE. The result of using `underset` in combination with `xleftarrow` is also not satisfying because there is a lot of white space between the "F" and "E" (See MWE).

In case of the latter, I just would like to have an arrow below the text "Fed_t" pointing to the left hand side of equation (3). When this is done in a way that there is no extra space between letters, I think it is the best option to highlight what I want. Anyone who can help me with this?

Other suggestions to highlight the effect of "Fed_t" to the left hand side of equation 3 are also very welcome!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\let\underbrace\LaTeXunderbrace
\let\overbrace\LaTeXoverbrace
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Methodology}
\framesubtitle{General framework}
In the case of the eurozone:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\underbrace{\Delta R^n_t = f (Fed_t}_{\text{Fed signalling effect}}, ECB_t, News_t ) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{itemize}
\item Fed UMP announcements $\Rightarrow$ $\Delta R^n_{t}$, $\Delta TPP^n_t$ and  $\Delta TPR^n_t$. First, cancel out the effects through signalling:
\end{itemize}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta(Y^n_t - R^n_t)=  \Delta TPP^n_t + \Delta TPR^n_t  \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In case of the eurozone:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta(Y^n_t - R^n_t) =  f (\underset{\xleftarrow[\text{Fed signalling}]{}} Fed_t , ECB_t, News_t, Sovereign_t) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to load `amsmath` since `mathtools` loads it anyway.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

An understack, with the`\useanchorwidth` parameter set `T` will not let the size of the understacked material affect the spacing of the the stack's "anchor".

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\let\underbrace\LaTeXunderbrace
\let\overbrace\LaTeXoverbrace
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Methodology}
\framesubtitle{General framework}
In the case of the eurozone:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\underbrace{\Delta R^n_t = f (Fed_t}_{\text{Fed signalling effect}}, ECB_t, News_t ) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{itemize}
\item Fed UMP announcements $\Rightarrow$ $\Delta R^n_{t}$, $\Delta TPP^n_t$ and  $\Delta TPR^n_t$. First, cancel out the effects through signalling:
\end{itemize}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta(Y^n_t - R^n_t)=  \Delta TPP^n_t + \Delta TPR^n_t  \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In case of the eurozone:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta(Y^n_t - R^n_t) =  f (\stackengine{3pt}{Fed_t}{%
  \scriptstyle\xleftarrow[\text{Fed signalling}]{}}{U}{c}{F}{T}{S} , ECB_t, News_t, Sovereign_t) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, you can use a `\mathclap` to achieve essentially the identical result:

```
\begin{aligned}
\Delta(Y^n_t - R^n_t) =  f (\underset{\mathclap{\xleftarrow[
\text{Fed signalling}]{}}} {Fed_t} , ECB_t, News_t, Sovereign_t) \\
\end{aligned}
```

**FOLLOW UP**

To answer the OP's comment below, to get right alignment of the arrow under the `FED_t`, one can use

```
\begin{aligned}
\Delta(Y^n_t - R^n_t) =  f (\stackengine{5pt}{Fe}{%
  \scriptstyle\xleftarrow[\text{Fed signalling}]{}}{U}{r}{F}{T}{S}d_t ,
  ECB_t, News_t, Sovereign_t) \\
\end{aligned}
```

[image]

This was achieved by changing the `c` alignment of the stack to `r` alignment; making that alignment occur after `Fe` rather than after `Fed_t`; and increasing the stackunder gap to 5pt.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and good answer. However, in case of `useanchorwidth`, how can the arrow be more placed to the left? So that it starts in the middle of Fed and points towards the left hand side? (now it starts below ECB)

Comment: @peter There are two things: 1) change the `c` argument of `\stackengine` to `r` for right alignment; and 2) instead up putting `Fed_t` as the 2nd argument to `\stackengine`, just put `Fe`, and place the `d_t` after the last `\stackengine` argument.  I will edit my answer to show it.

Answer (score 4):

This matches the `\underbrace` you had in the first example:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Methodology}

In case of the eurozone:
\begin{equation}
  {\mathop{
     \underleftarrow{\Delta(Y^n_t - R^n_t) =  f (Fed_t}
  }_{\text{Fed signalling effect}}}, ECB_t, News_t, Sovereign_t)
\end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]